# Need help modifying a tip calculator in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calculator

I'm putting a "tithe" calculator for a church website. I converted a "tip calculator" and modified it into what I have so far which is great, but I do need to make some last adjustments.

1. I need to make it so that, when you type in your amount (price of meal), you can put commas or periods in between the numbers. Right now, it can only accept numbers.
2. Right now there's an option underneath where you can pick the percentage (10%, 15%, 20%, etc.)... I need to take that out so that there's no option to choose the percentage. When you press "Calculate" it should just automatically calculate 10% of the amount. Here is the JS code underneath. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```js
//target calculate button and retrieve user input from bill amount entry field
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var billAmt = document.getElementsByClassName('userBillAmt')[0].value;
  billAmt = parseInt(billAmt);

  //get input from tip percentage entry field
  var tipPercentage = document.getElementsByClassName('userTipPercentage')[0].value;
  //convert tip percentage from string to usable number
  tipPercentage = parseInt(tipPercentage);

  //append amount the user should tip to the DOM/page
  document.getElementById('tipHere').innerHTML = '$' + calculate(billAmt, tipPercentage).toFixed(2);

  //function to convert user bill amount and desired tip percentage to the amount they should tip
  function calculate(billAmt, tipPercentage) {
    var tipAmt = (tipPercentage / 100) * billAmt;
    return tipAmt;
  }
});
```

Comment: All the code is their for you. Just a few tweaks and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. replace parseInt(billAmt) with parseFloat function call. That way your input value is treated as decimal value.
2. tipPercentage variable should be replaced with constant value 10. In your case var tipPercentage = 10.

Comment: What would I put in the parentheses after "parseFloat"?

Comment: You should put the same variable as parameter to parseFloat function call as before. billAmt.